# AWS Aurora cluster endpoint usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

If I use an AWS Aurora MYSQL database with 2 read replicas, do I need to use a different connection string for reading and writing, or does the cluster endpoint route the traffic for me? If this is the case,  for an application that makes fewer writes would it be sensible to make the read replicas larger instances (more powerful)  than the primary as it will hardly be used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two connections - one for reads, one for writes.

The cluster can't know if you're planning on reading or writing when you open a connection.

Comment: What's the point of having two readers then if you have to choose which one to connect to? I feel like the cluster should be able to route traffic.

Comment: You don't have two readers:  There is a cluster read endpoint that will connect you to one of the read-only nodes.  There is no way for the database to know what you are planning to do when you open a connection - it is up to the application developer to decide when a connection will be used for reads or writes.

Comment: yesterday Ok, well ours has two readers and one writer. So the custer endpoint will just connect you to one of them? If since that is the case, I have to make queries to find out what I have connected to and then reconnect? Or I have to query AWS with the ARN to find out the names of the nodes and connect that way? Especially if I have many more writers than readers.